# HTML <select> what is the name of on select event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

Does the HTML "select" element have an on select event? what exactly is the name of the event?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Is [`onchange`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 25):

It's also worth mentioning that this doesn't fire if the selection doesn't change (seems self explanatory). As far as I know there is no event that fires when a user drops down the selectbox and then reselects the original value.

Comment: @wakeless thanks, I knew the search on Google for this one edge case was going to be tough. Glad you piped up to cover the question of the user selecting the same value.

Answer (score 20):

It's [onchange Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912(VS.85).aspx).

jQuery wraps it in the `.change` helper. If using plain Javascript then use `addEventListner('change', function...)`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

// If using jQuery
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#list").attr( "selectedIndex", -1 );
    $("#list").change( function() {
        $("#answer").text( $("#list option:selected").val() );
    });
});
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

// Plain Javascript:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    var selectList = document.getElementById("list");
    var divAnswer  = document.getElementById("answer");
    selectList.addEventListener("change", function(changeEvent) {
        divAnswer.textContent = selectList.value;
    });
});
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="answer">No answer</div>
    <form>
        Answer
        <select id="list">
            <option value="Answer A">A</option>
            <option value="Answer B">B</option>
            <option value="Answer C">C</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The world is not jQuery. Probably best to respond with a generic JS response if the O.P. didn't explicitly ask for jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of input type, whenever a form input changes value, an `onchange` event should always be thrown. (With the exception of buttons, as they are not really input devices as such.)

Comment: Worth noting that when you're using a <select>, the event is fired immediately on selection, whereas with something like a text input, it's not fired until you move off the field. Checkboxes and radio buttons are fiddly with onchange, so it's best to use onclick for those.